# WinSock send() hook causing access violation

Tags: c++, hook, winsock, inline-assembly

I want to write a "man-in-the-middle" program to help me debug a network application I'm developing. After some Google'ing (I had no idea how to do this at all), I came up with the idea that I had to create a hook (I've worked with hooks before in other languages, but they were much simpler) to intercept WinSock's `send`. According to various articles, I have to modify the first 5 bytes of the function to jump to my function, do some work, and jump back. I found [this code](http://theundead.atspace.com/Blog/Cplusplusssendhook.txt) online, which I rewrote in a console application. Here is what I came up with:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <WinSock2.h>
#include <windows.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")
#define JMP(frm, to) (int)(((int)to - (int)frm) - 5);

#define DEF_PORT 27015

using namespace std;

bool HookSend();
void UnhookSend();

DWORD SendOriginal          = 0;
DWORD SendReturn            = 0;
DWORD *SendHookFunc         = 0;
DWORD OldProtection         = 0;

char* send_buffer;
int send_sizeofdata         = 0;
SOCKET send_s;
int send_flags              = 0;

HINSTANCE hWinSock          = 0;

void __declspec(naked) __stdcall SendHook()
{
    __asm
    { 
        mov     edi,edi
        push    ebp
        mov     ebp, esp
        mov     eax, [ebp+0x08]         /* Param 1 : Socket */
        mov     send_s, eax
        mov     eax, [ebp+0x0C]         /* Param 2 : buffer */
        mov     [send_buffer], eax
        mov     eax, [ebp+0x10]         /*Param 3 : Size*/
        mov     send_sizeofdata, eax
        mov     eax, [ebp+0x14]         /*Param 4 : flags*/
        mov     send_flags, eax
        jmp     SendReturn
    }
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    WSADATA wsaData;
    SOCKET soket;
    sockaddr_in soketDesc;

    char buf[256];

    cout << "Packet Reader by Timothy Volpe" << endl;
    cout << "Program will read packets sent" << endl << endl;

    cout << "Loading WinSock" << endl;
    if((hWinSock = LoadLibrary("ws2_32.dll")) == NULL)
    {
        cout << "Failed to load WinSock library" << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    cout << "Starting WinSock API" << endl;

    if(WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsaData) != NO_ERROR)
    {
        cout << "Failed to load WinSock API (Error:" << WSAGetLastError() << ")" << endl;
        cout << "Press enter to exit" << endl;
        cin.get();
        return -1;
    }

    cout << "Hooking send()" << endl;
    if(!HookSend())
    {
        cout << "Press enter to exit" << endl;
        cin.get();
        return -1;
    }
    cout << "Hooked successfully!" << endl;

    cout << "Creating socket" << endl;
    soket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if(soket == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        cout << "Failed to create socket (Error:" << WSAGetLastError() << ")" << endl;
        UnhookSend();
        cout << "Press enter to exit" << endl;
        cin.get();
        return -1;
    }

    cout << "Connecting socket to port " << DEF_PORT << endl;
    soketDesc.sin_family        = AF_INET;
    soketDesc.sin_addr.s_addr   = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    soketDesc.sin_port          = htons(DEF_PORT);
    if(connect(soket, (SOCKADDR*)&soketDesc, sizeof(soketDesc)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        cout << "Failed to connect socket (Error:" << WSAGetLastError() << ")" << endl;
        UnhookSend();
        cout << "Press enter to exit" << endl;
        cin.get();
        return -1;
    }

    cout << "Enter some data to send (MAX 256):" << endl;
    cin.get(buf, 256); //Read 256 chars
    cout << "Sending \"" << buf << "\"" << endl;

    //Send the data
    send(soket, buf, (int)sizeof(buf), 0);

    //Close
    closesocket(soket);
    WSACleanup();

    UnhookSend();

    cout << endl << "Press enter to exit" << endl;
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore();
    cin.get();

    return 0;
}

bool HookSend()
{
    //Get the new function's address
    SendHookFunc = (DWORD*)SendHook;
    //Get the send() function's address
    SendOriginal = (DWORD)GetProcAddress(hWinSock, "send");
    //Get the return address, which is 5 bytes past the start
    SendReturn = SendOriginal + 5;
    printf("SEND\tStart: %x\t Return: %x\n", SendOriginal, SendReturn);
    //Change protection for the first 5 bytes
    VirtualProtect((void*)SendOriginal, 0x05, PAGE_READWRITE, &OldProtection);
    *(BYTE*)(SendOriginal) = 0xe9;
    *(int*)(SendOriginal+1) = JMP(SendOriginal, SendHookFunc);

    return true;
}

void UnhookSend()
{
    cout << "Unhooking..." << endl;
    //Restore the old stuff
    *(WORD*)SendOriginal = 0xFF8B;
    *(BYTE*)(SendOriginal+1) = 0x55;
    *(WORD*)(SendOriginal+3) = 0xEC8B;
    //Restore protection
    VirtualProtect((void*)SendOriginal, 0x05, OldProtection, &OldProtection);
}
```

But, it does not work, as I get an access violation on `socket()`. If I remove the calls to `HookSend` and `UnhookSend`, it runs fine. If I change around the order of the calls (such as putting `WSAStartup` after `HookSend`), it crashes on the first WinSock function. So I think I'm like corrupting the entire library or something, I'm really not too sure. To be honest, I just learned assembly today (well, Visual Studio's version of it). It's pretty easy to grip, and I understand the assembly in this code, I believe. My code is almost identical to the code from the web, so I don't know whats wrong. I wonder if it's an OS conflict, or a project settings thing, or something entirely different.

I'm at a loss here, so any pointers in the right direction would be great! Also, if I'm going at this completely wrong (like theres a better method), feel free to let me know. And I do know about [Microsoft's Detours](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/detours/), but I'd rather not use it for something this simple (and I also don't like the idea of a non-commercial use license lingering over my head, even if this will probably never be released).

Comment: This feels like the kind of code that a virus would use. Why can't you just tunnel the traffic through something that seems legitimate to the OS and antivirus?

Comment: Why not write an LSP or use Detours for injections?

Comment: Those 5 bytes of the original function that you overwrite and skip, do they correspond to the first instructions of your hook routine?

Comment: If you are interested I can show you how to hook using the hook engine from our company. Regarding the license, you can use it freely: only a dialog fade-in and fade-out automatically. It take cares of the injection and parameters parsing.

Comment: My code probably looks suspicious because I honestly had absolutely no idea how to do this. I guess I was technically hacking, but I was hacking my own program... so...? (I also got a lot of tutorials on 'strange' websites...) I've given up on this. It seemed like a good idea at the time, and I had fun. But I don't really need it. If I do I'll use Detours, as everyone has suggested :)

Answer (score 2):

It is rarely necessary to debug the actual API calls themselves in such a brute-force manner.  You could just use a packet sniffer like Wireshark to capture and analyze the network traffic that is being transmitted.  But if you must debug the API calls, you are essentially trying to manually implement a Detour, so you really should use Microsoft's Detours library to implement a real Detour correctly.  A better option is to use WinSock's built-in debugging functionality and not hook the API functions at all.  Let the OS handle the hooking and logging of calls and parameters for you.

Comment: I'll admit, I did do it the hard way just for the adventure. But I couldn't find much about how to view all the packets sent out in real time on the web. It didn't seem necessary to get Detours for something I'll probably never do again.

Comment: If all you want to do is look at the transmitted packets, then use a packet sniffer, such as Wireshark.

Answer (score 1):

You're not checking the return value for the call to VirtualProtect; my guess is that it's not succeeding and you don't have the necessary rights possibly.  Are you running this code as an "Administrator" and do you have the Windows UAC stuff disabled?

Update your code to examine the return value of VirtualProtect and let us know if that reveals anything.

Comment: I'll check the return value. As far as I know, it always runs as admin. I have 1 account on my machine, and it's an admin account. All executables run as admin by default. And I disabled UAC long ago, hated that thing...